How can a VS Code extension tell when the TypeScript language service is ready for queries
I'm building a VS Code extension that issues quickinfo requests to the built-in TypeScript language server. The goal is to find symbols that have an any type. I'm issues these queries using a snippet from the vscode-twoslash-queries extension:
/** Leverages the `tsserver` protocol to try to get the type info at the given `position`. */
export async function quickInfoRequest(model: vscode.TextDocument, position: vscode.Position) {
  const { scheme, fsPath, authority, path } = model.uri;
  return await vscode.commands.executeCommand<QuickInfoResponse | undefined>(
    "typescript.tsserverRequest",
    "quickinfo",
    {
      file: scheme === 'file' ? fsPath : `^/${scheme}/${authority || 'ts-nul-authority'}/${path.replace(/^\//, '')}`,
      line: position.line + 1,
      offset: position.character,
    } satisfies FileLocationRequestArgs
  );
}

This works well… but only if I issue the queries after the language server has had time to fully load and "settle down." If I issue a query involving an import too early, the language service will respond with an any type. This results in lots of spurious warnings:

I'd like to wait until the TypeScript server is ready to give its final answer. Is there any way I can check whether it's still in the process of loading? Is there some event my extension can listen for to find out that the server is ready for queries?
